# Magento 2: Cart Subtotal shows Original Price in place of Special Price

Tags: price, special-price, magento-1.9.2

I have an online multistore website.

In this website, we are facing an issue in which `subtotal` on the cart is not displaying special price for some products. In place, it shows the actual price with tax. Products show the `special price` in`catalogue` page and`product page`.

What I found now is, If I try to update the `special price` by `selecting default` view. It shows the correct price in `cart page` too. And when I remove that special price from default store view, after that also it shows correctly.

It works fine for `some products` but for some products it not. If anyone has faced this issue earlier, please help me with it.

In this issue, further, I found that `_initItem()` method is called twice in which it sets the price of an item. First time when it is called, the final price of the product is special price and on the second time, it gives the `original price`.

If anyone can help now, please let me know.

Comment: try reindexing once, also is those special prices gave under `catalog> products` section or did you created `catalog price rules` ?

Comment: It is given under catalog > products. Please check my edited question, what change I found on it.

Comment: check these links once  : [link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117969/magento-does-not-show-special-price-in-cart-and-checkout-but-everywhere-else) , [link2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39988/sale-price-is-not-showing) ,  [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039927/magento-cart-price-issue)

Comment: This links didn't helped. Not getting any clue that why it is happening.

Comment: compare those products [ one which is displaying special price on cart and one which is not ] check all product configuration......

Comment: can you try disable one of those products and recreate same product and enable it and check for that.....